# Avoiding invalidated pointers while using WinAPI (Windows Core Audio)

Tags: c++, winapi, com

We are using an instantiation of `IMMNotificationClient` to notify us of changes that happen with a specific audio device (the Foo sound blaster), but when a Foo blaster that has not yet been installed on the computer yet is plugged in, the program seg-faults (throws an Access Violation) inside of the `IMMNotificationClient::OnDeviceStateChanged` function

Here's what's causing this to happen as far as I can tell:

1. plug in the new Foo blaster
2. Windows fires off a device state change notification to the IMMNotificationClient
3. Before the `IMMNotificationClient::OnDeviceStateChanged` function can finish execution, Windows invalidates the COM object.

This invalidation happens at seemingly random points in the `IMMNotificationClient::OnDeviceStateChanged` function.

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h>
#include <string>

class FooSoundBlasterNotifier: public IMMNotificationClient {
    //private member variables
    const char * FOO_BLASTER_NAME = "Foo Blaster";


public:
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceStateChanged(LPCWSTR pDeviceId, DWORD newState)
    {
        IMMDeviceEnumerator *pDeviceEnumerator;
        IMMDevice *pDevice;
        IPropertyStore *pStore;
        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
        hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pDeviceEnumerator);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pDeviceEnumerator->GetDevice(pDeviceId, &pDevice);

            if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                hr = pDevice->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &pStore);

                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PROPVARIANT variant;
                    PropVariantInit(&variant);

                    hr = pStore->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &variant);

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        //Code usually crashes about right here
                        std::wstring friendlyNameW(variant.pwszVal);
                        std::string friendlyName(friendlyNameW.begin(), friendlyNameW.end());
                        if(friendlyName.find(FOO_BLASTER_NAME) != std::string::npos)
                        {
                            //Log the information about state change
                        }
                        //release
                    }
                    //all
                }
                //COM
            }
            //Objects
        }

        return S_OK;
    }

    //Declare other needed functions
};
```

How can I avoid using an invalidated Windows COM object? Baring that, how do I successfully recover from an access violation without having to close down the whole program?

**EDIT**

Here's a call trace of where the code is failing:

```
common_strnlen_simd<1,1,unsigned short>(const unsigned short * const string, const unsigned __int64 maximum_count) Line 152
    at minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\string\strnlen.cpp(152)
common_strnlen<1,unsigned short>(const unsigned short * const string, const unsigned __int64 maximum_count) Line 185
    at minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\string\strnlen.cpp(185)
wcslen(const wchar_t * string) Line 219
    at minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\string\strnlen.cpp(219)
[External Code]
FooSoundBlaster::OnDeviceStateChanged(const wchar_t * pwstrDeviceId, unsigned long dwNewState)
[External Code]
```

Comment: Who is managing the reference count on the `FooSoundBlasterNotifier`?

Comment: In the actual code, FooSoundBlaster handles its own reference count and extends the `AddRef` and `Release` functions declared by IUnknown. Was that a good answer? I'm not sure if I understand your question entirely.

Comment: possible you wrong manage reference count, etc. also based on your info only impossible say where error. *at seemingly random points in the* - so hard locate it exactly ? at which operator, asm code ?

Comment: I mean who is making sure that there is an outstanding AddRef on the FooSoundBlaster? Maybe you have a race condition where the last reference is released while the OnDeviceStateChanged is still running.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that the reference count for FooSoundBlaster never goes below 0 since `Release` is never called on FooSoundBlaster for the duration of the program.
@RbMm 31 the exact asm instruction is: `vmovdqu     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rax]`

Comment: @Raymond Chen The design of the project is to have a FooSoundBlaster present and active for the duration of program execution. Having written the code for and referencing FooSoundBlaster, I am confident that the reference count is always above 0.

Comment: this instruction from which c++ operator ? where exactly is crash?

Comment: @RbMm The error is being thrown during the constructor call in wstring: `std::wstring friendlyNameW(variant.pwszVal);` found right below my comment about the code crashing in the example code. Which C++ operation inside of the constructor is failing? I'm not sure since I am unable to view the source code. I can however provide a stack trace.

Comment: obvious that `variant.pwszVal` is not valid `BSTR`  (unicode) string. you not check that `variant` have `VT_BSTR` - what is actual type of variant ?what is  value. exception when you access which address ?

Comment: in what problem set breakpoint after `pStore->GetValue` and check `variant` returned

Comment: @RbMm Remember that `nullptr` is a legal `BSTR`, but `std::wstring`'s constructor doesn't permit that.

Comment: @RaymondChen - yes, legal. but not for `wcslen`. so i and ask exception at which memory location ? 0 ?

Comment: Adding a check for variant.pwszVal != NULL solved the problem.

Comment: @Jack - please answer yourself if you're happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem isn't an invalidation of the IMMDevice object, but rather `variant.pwszVal` being null. A simple check like this:

```
if(variant.pwszVal /* != NULL, there you go Paul! :) */)
{
    friendlyNameW = variant.pwszVal;
}
```

should solve the problem in the above code.